# Incorrect leaving date on Resignation

Tags: resignation

I recently resigned from my position.  The contract states that I must give 4 weeks' notice.  At the time I miscalculated and gave them 2 months instead of one.  My manager questioned me and I confirmed the error.  However, the end date was never changed on the system.

I gave my notice in writing on the company site. My boss told me about the date on our next encounter and I confirmed it was in error. Now two weeks later they are saying I have to resubmit it but from today’s date and not the original date.

Comment: Did you give notice in writing?

Comment: It depends on what is signed.  If you signed it, it's what is on the paper.

Comment: Depends on the country/jurisdiction. And what does your manager say when you ask him.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you want to check, is if there is a record of the resignation. Most contracts will only state that you have to notify them that you are resigning and have no restrictions on the media/method you choose to do so. At my first job, I just straight up told my boss, I will be leave after this date. No letter, email or phone call. I just stopped showing up at work.  If you have a written record of this, you can notify your company that you have already given notice two weeks ago and present the proof. The company should understand.

Even with no record, your manager should know about the situation and you should be able to leave as you had originally planned. This is because hiring an unwilling employee can be risky for a business. After all, they would still need to pay you for a Month, and during that month you could perform very poorly. So its not in their best interest either to keep you longer than needed.

At the end of the day, it really depends on what is in your contract. If there are no specifics you should be good to go if you have verbally informed your boss that you are leaving at a set date.